# Parse picklist value field in a formula

Tags: formula

For example I have: Monday, March 20th 11:30 PM
I want to have the formula parse this and return just: Monday, March 20th

The formula I have now is 
`TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT( FIELDNAME ), RIGHT(TEXT(FIELDNAME), 8), ""))` but it is not working.

Comment: If your text will vary in length you may want to rewrite `RIGHT`. Is this a datetime field?

Comment: No this is a picklist value

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

`TRIM(MID(FIELDNAME, 1, LEN(FIELDNAME)-8))`

it will return: Monday, March 20th

For picklist field use like this:

`TRIM(MID(TEXT(FIELDNAME), 1, LEN(TEXT(FIELDNAME))-8))`

Comment: Date: {!TRIM(MID(Contact.Field__c, 1, LEN(Contact.Field__c) - 8))} This is not returning a value when I try to use it in an Text Email Template.  Don't you need to use the "TEXT" formula to convert a picklist to a string?

Comment: I have given you the formula

Comment: I know you have given the formula, but I am saying it is not working when used in an Email Template

Comment: create a separate formula field and use that formula field in email template

Comment: When I try to create a workflow rule formula, I get an error stating the field is a picklist field, picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Comment: if field is picklist you need to use TEXT(Contact.Field__c)